# X509Certificate2 Public Key Signature Algorithm http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256

Tags: x509certificate2

I have a certificate that has a Signature algorithm of sha256RSA but when the cert is loaded into an X509Certificate2 object the Public Key Signature algorithm is http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1 but I would expect it to be http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256.  Below is a quick sample of how I am grabbing the cert and viewing the signature algorithm.  The reason this is an issue is that Web Service Enhancements (WSE) uses this value to map to CryptoConfig to find the SignatureFormatter.  Without loading the rsa-sha256 formatter we are not able to support SHA256 signatures.  Moving away from WSE to something like WCF is not really an option for us at this point.  I have wondered if it might have something to do with not using the Enhanced CSP but don't know how to force that either.  Any help/thoughts are much appreciated.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = String.Empty;

    List<X509Certificate2> certs = LoadX509Certificates();

    foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in certs)
    {
        textBox1.Text += cert.PublicKey.Key.SignatureAlgorithm + "\r\n";
    }
}

public List<X509Certificate2> LoadX509Certificates()
{
    List<X509Certificate2> certificateList = null;

    // copied implementation from X509TokenProvider but don't throw on more than on certificate
    X509Certificate2Collection certificateCollection = null;
    X509Store x509Store = new X509Store("My",
        StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    try
    {
        x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        certificateCollection = x509Store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
            "93 f4 3a cd b2 6c 79 74 1c 55 4f d1 43 94 37 30 98 82 48 74", false);

        if (certificateCollection.Count < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format("No certificate found"));
        }

        foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in certificateCollection)
        {
            if (cert.HasPrivateKey)
            {
                var tempKey = cert.PrivateKey;
            }
        }

        certificateList = certificateCollection.Cast<X509Certificate2>().ToList();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (certificateCollection != null)
        {
            foreach (X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2 in x509Store.Certificates)
            {
                if (!certificateCollection.Contains(x509Certificate2))
                {
                    x509Certificate2.Reset();
                }
            }
        }

        x509Store.Close();
    }

    return (certificateList);
}
```

Certificate details from OpenSSL

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            2a:ac:6c:cc:22:6e:cb:97:4f:2a:4a:91:42:00:74:b4
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=\x00_\x00R\x00o\x00o\x00t\x00 \x00C\x00A\x00 \x00T\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00_\x002\x005\x006\x00.\x00e\x00t\x00.\x00l\x00o\x00c\x00a\x00l
        Validity
            Not Before: Feb  9 14:21:51 2015 GMT
            Not After : Dec 31 23:59:59 2039 GMT
        Subject: CN=\x00C\x00l\x00i\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00_\x00T\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00_\x002\x005\x006\x00.\x00e\x00t\x00.\x00l\x00o\x00c\x00a\x00l
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (1024 bit)
                Modulus (1024 bit):
                    00:af:77:1c:64:3a:ea:0b:72:df:e7:6d:c0:f6:74:
                    df:21:9c:e4:98:07:4c:b5:d9:7d:a3:96:88:a8:eb:
                    fd:bf:d6:8c:71:ac:3d:38:c2:42:b4:1d:83:18:d7:
                    2b:80:a2:06:3d:74:99:64:fe:a8:47:52:0e:d1:a2:
                    ff:8a:5d:af:a3:a9:4e:27:3e:2c:30:48:68:22:76:
                    ea:9a:e3:0f:d5:fa:e9:5c:35:f9:d2:dd:28:55:40:
                    ec:52:86:b9:c0:f9:30:c6:2d:94:0a:3b:7a:0f:00:
                    25:c9:eb:04:6c:85:d6:3e:6b:14:7e:a4:aa:8e:1b:
                    90:72:c0:76:91:f6:7b:e6:15
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            2.5.29.1: 
                0g....b....O"....o.q.A0?1=0;..U...4._.R.o.o.t. .C.A. .T.e.s.t._.2.5.6...e.t...l.o.c.a.l......B.L.@......p
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        22:16:ad:44:69:27:67:93:0d:e7:43:4a:53:ee:58:ec:b1:56:
        08:b2:49:fe:0d:3d:53:83:71:01:12:a7:0b:f5:d6:47:1c:5d:
        f2:00:9b:61:0f:17:13:aa:24:0e:f4:db:97:85:da:47:e8:4c:
        39:7a:52:ee:4b:ac:8c:f5:25:33:9f:aa:33:53:c5:8d:b3:c6:
        27:e4:92:b3:b8:d2:aa:a9:b4:f0:8a:83:89:34:35:65:b2:69:
        d0:4c:c1:48:f0:ea:01:a2:aa:80:d6:fb:f6:09:02:ff:00:10:
        19:94:ad:20:f0:92:27:6b:6c:75:72:c4:04:a1:40:4b:16:60:
        84:fe
```

Comment: Are you in a position to use openssl to view the details of the certificate in the keystore and see what it thinks the signature algorithm is?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have added the output from OpenSSL to the original question.

Answer (score 3):

You are confused by property name.
`sha256RSA` is certificate signature algorithm and is not related to embedded public key at all. [SignatureAlgorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.signaturealgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx) is a part of `X509Certificate2` object, not public key. What you see in the [RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignatureAlgorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.signaturealgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx) property is a default signature algorithm in a particular implementation of an RSA algorithm. And as per documentation, it is always set to `http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1`

Comment: Thank you for the response.Yes I have come across that so another way to ask the question is if there is a service provider that can be used which would indicate sha256?  And if so how would you have the x509Store or x509Certificate2 specify that?  The MS WSE pipeline does the comparison and I'm not seeing a way around that.  The algorithm specified in the soap document must match the algorithm in the service provider.

Comment: it is not related to CSP, it is related to an RSA algorithm implementation. .NET has only one RSA implementation in `RsaCryptoServiceProvider`.